# BitSet initialized with byte[] returns unexpected bits

Tags: java, bitset

I'm writing a test for a bit reader class. I have a ByteBuffer that is the source for the reader and I initialize it with 32 random bytes. Then I create a BitBuffer with the ByteBuffer as initial.

this is the byte[] I have:

```
[-35, -15, 33, -71, -107, 4, -68, 60, -47, -116, -85, -3, -86, -16, 51, 77, 22, -47, -41, 64, 50, 38, -6, -110, 69, 87, -38, -101, 58, 15, 70, 66]
```

when I translate that manually into bits the output should be

```
1101 1101 1111 0001 0010 0001 1011 1001 1011 1001 1001 0101 0000 0100 1011 1100 ...
```

I would expect the BitSet bits 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7 ... to be set, but in debug display it shows

```
{0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, ....
```

I can't really see this matching but I don't understand why. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be taking the 0th bit as the rightmost bit of the leftmost byte, iterating backwards through the bits in a byte, then forwards through the bytes.

Bytes 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, and 7 are set:

```
7654 3210
1101 1101
```

Then the 8th bit is set (the rightmost bit of the second byte from the left)...

Comment: Now it makes sense. But still very unexpected.